# Only the first half of program runs

Tags: java, printing, heap

I need to print a Heap stored as an array. I have created a class to do this. However, when I run the program, it only runs the first half of the main method. Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int newNum;
        Heap heap = new Heap(21);

        //Creates a heap of 20 random integers
        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            newNum = r.nextInt(1000);
            heap.add(newNum);
        }

        System.out.println("Completed Heap:");
        heap.print(1, 0);

        //Removes the max of the Heap and prints each new iteration
        for(int j = 20; j >= 1; j--)
        {
            System.out.println("\nRemoved " + heap.removeMax() + " from Heap:");
            heap.print(1, 0);
        }
    }
```

It prints out the completed heap, but is supposed to print the heap after the max is removed until the heap is completely removed. However, it prints the completed one and then seems to get stuck. Any ideas/suggestions?

EDIT: the print method of my heap class:

```
public void print(int start, int level)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        int left = start * 2, right = left + 1;
        if(right <= heap.length - 1)
        {
            print(right, level + 1);
        }
        if(heap[start] == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= level; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("    ");
            }
            System.out.print(heap[start]);
        }
        if(left <= heap.length - 1)
        {
            print(left, level + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What implementation of `Heap` are you using?

Comment: It must be being stuck in `heap.print`. Please post that.

Comment: I will edit my post with the print method. I am VERY open to suggestions there because it is something I had a bit of trouble coming up with and likely screwed up

Comment: @Frolf182 Probably just a bad terminating condition on a loop. It happens. You should learn to debug though. Probably could have solved your self in less time than it took to write the question.

Comment: Oh jeez. More complicated than I thought it'd be, and I'm on my phone and don't have the full implementation, so I can't test it myself. In the System println statement at the top, replace the empty string with something more noticeable (like a line of dashes), and run it again. Does it print the line forever?

Comment: No it stops at the end of the first Heap print

Comment: The problem is in `removeMax` method, otherwise you would see at least one more print statements in second loop